# Function field of open set of subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Fulton, in his book Algebraic Curves on classical algebraic geometry, says that if $X$ is an irreducible algebraic set and $V \subset X$ an open subset, then the field of fractions $k(V) = k(X)$; subsequently, he defines the dimension of an abstract variety and says that in the above scenario, $dim(V) = dim(X)$ (Proposition 10, p. 75). Here is my confusion: If $Y \supset X$ is another irreducible algebraic set, then it is not necessarily true that $k(Y) = k(X)$! (E.g., $Y = \mathbf{A}^n$ and $X$ is any algebraic subset.) Does this mean that we have to think of the function field and dimension of an abstract variety relative to a particular "base closed set"?

I am taking a look at the book after a break of a few months so sorry if I forgot something obvious. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten that $V\subset X$ should be an open subset. The function field and dimension of a variety are intrinsic concepts which do not depend on any embedding.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete explanation (sketched by a friend Elliot Kienzle): We can prove topologically that if $X$ is irreducible and $U \subset X$ open, then $U$'s closure $\overline{U} = X$. Let's say $U = X \cap W$ for some open $W$. This follows since:

1. $X \setminus U = X \cap W^C$, so $X \setminus U$ is closed.
2. $\overline{U} = \bigcap_{V \supset U : V\text{ closed}}$, so $\overline{U} \subset X$.

Thus, supposing that $\overline{U} \neq X$, we have $X = \overline{U} \cup (X \setminus U)$ (a union of two proper closed sets), so $X$ is reducible.

(As a consequence, it cannot be the case that $U$ is an open subset of two distinct irreducible sets $X$ and $Y$.)